# Visual Studio Code JSX View mess

Tags: reactjs, jsx

When I Save JSX code in visual studio code everything is getting mess like in the image attached
[image: view]

Comment: You probably need React in scope to use JSX. `import React from 'react'`. Your file should probably have .jsx extension as well.

Comment: check your extensions, you might have a Nodejs Snippets installed that might format your .js files

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring ESLint or Prettier.
If you have already configured any of these linters, please update the post including their configurations respectively.